# Как сделать такой список?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает. Как называется бибилотека для отображения такого списка с алфавитом с права?

Comment: Спросите у создателей прошивки MIUI Russia.

Comment: не совсем то, https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants, можете поискать здесь https://android-arsenal.com

Comment: вот еще вариант https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5553

Comment: вот еще [некоторое количество](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+alphabet+recyclerview&type=Repositories) вариантов :)

Comment: https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll
и
https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants
как объединить?

Comment: никак, но можно всегда написать свой RecyclerView